# Usage of Spanish word "Tresbolillo" in electrical distribution

Tags: wiring, terminology

I am from Spain, and in this country is very common to use the word "Tresbolillo" to designate the distribution of electrical cables but not for a stringing connection, as it says in a website explaining electrical stringing methods.

[image]

As I remember in Spain we use "Tresbolillo" to designate for example cables distribution as an equilateral triangle, like this photo:

[image]

Could anyone explain to me the meaning or the objective to use the word "Tresbolillo" in this case of a leapfrog method in PV.

Comment: I'm afraid this might not get any good answers; most of us here don't speak Spanish, so even though your question is in English, because it's about terminology used in Spanish, I don't think many of us will be able to comment.

Comment: I recognise the fragment "tres-" in the word you're asking about as meaning "three", but I don't know what "bolillo" means. Is that also a word in Spanish? What would its English translation be in an electrical context?

Comment: Also, it might be good to explain what you mean by "not a stringing connection".

Comment: `Tresbolillo o salto de rana` ... maybe `daisychain`

Comment: @Hearth yes "Tres" is three but the word "bolillo" I've been looking around on the internet and I have also found an exmple with bread...but in this case it has no senese. From now on I don't match the word "Bolillo" with any other. And yes is a word from Spanis

Comment: @jsotola Yes but Daisychain is another lind of stringing

Comment: `bolillo` translates to a type of baked product that looks like a `roll` ... maybe that is the word ... try at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Tresbolillo is a kind of pattern to distribute holes or plants or anything in equilateral triangles, instead of just rows.

Bolillo is an old word to designate patterns or techniques to knit (tejer). Check 'encaje de bolillos'

Comment: maybe electrically it refers to a `mesh network`